# Comparing values from 2 sheets

Tags: excel, vba

compare values from 1 column in a sheet to another column in a different sheet. If the value is the same, update the cell string to “Special”

I have a code that checks for type of each case I have, so when macros identifies that type it is the string in the cell changes for a specific name.

However, I need to create a new type named **Special**, when the value on alert_list.Range("E") **is NOT**  "Multi" and the value on alert_list.Range("C") **is** "Corp". Then the value on column F should be compared to the value on column B in a sheet named child_list to see if it is the same value and if it is the same then a string **Special** need appear in the cell on the place of "Corp" on alert_list.Range("C").

I create a list on column B in a sheet named child_list and I need to compare this values with the information in another sheet named alert_list column F.

everything above is working I am trying to create another step to be able to have a new type named Special.

```
If ABC.Range("E" & i).Value <> "Multi" And ABC.Range("C" & i).Value = "Corp" Then

            For k = 2 To Ch_lRow
            If ABC.Range("F" & i).Value <> TEXT.Range("B" & k).Value Then
                    'do nothing
            Else
    If alert_list.Range("F" & i).Value = TEXT.Range("B" & k).Value Then
            ABC.Range("C" & i).Value = "GOOD"
            End If
            Next
        End If
                Exit Sub
```

But for some reason unknown for me it is not working, I am not getting error However, or it jumps directly to exit sub or just nothing happen after run the code.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code to see where your code is doing or evaluate in the immediate pane to see if your statements are looking for what you think they are?

Comment: @SamuelEverson Yes I did, it seems like to be looking for alert_type "Multi"

Comment: Can you share a reproducible sample there's stuff missing here, and fix the indentation something seems off with your ifs and loops.

Comment: *Seems like*? Is it finding any values? Is it looking in the right place?
In your code, what is `i`?

Comment: @Warcupine Now I post the full code, everything is working fine and I am using the part where _when macro identifies that it has Corp and region is not Multi_ to do an extra step, to check if the current value on column F, exists in the list that I created in another sheet

Comment: @SamuelEverson it is looking in the correct place, and no it does not find the value.

Comment: Might be worth adding in some `Debug.Print` statements... `Debug.Print alert_list.Range("E" & i).Value` just before your `If alert_List.Range("E" & i).value` and also within your next `For k = 2 To Ch_lRow` loop add `Debug.Print alert_list.Range("F" & i).Value`. See what it spits out and then check your immidiate window values vs. your worksheet.

Comment: @SamuelEverson nothing appear on the immediate window for `Debug.Print alert_list.Range("E" & i).Value` and after the first IF it jump to Exit Sub

Comment: I think you're getting somewhere with debugging now - So your first `If` statement is not evaluating to `True` and  the `Exit Sub` is *outisde* the first `If` block - Basically, your first loop (incrementing `i`) will run once, and then the code will exit after your addition. When do you intend to `Exit Sub`?

Comment: @SamuelEverson only after all the data in the sheet was compared

Comment: @SamuelEverson in this case would be possible to say. if the value on column C is Corp but value on column E is not Multi then compared the values of column F to column B in child_sheet

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to explain in comments so here is an answer to explain.

You are executing an `Exit Sub` statement after your first `If...Then...Else` block.

If we use some proper indentation, it's much easier to identify this:

```
Dim Ch_lRow As Long
Ch_lRow = child_list.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

If alert_list.Range("E" & i).Value <> "Multi" And alert_list.Range("C" & i).Value = "Corp" Then

    For k = 2 To Ch_lRow
        If alert_list.Range("F" & i).Value <> child_list.Range("B" & k).Value Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            If alert_list.Range("F" & i).Value = child_list.Range("B" & k).Value Then
            alert_list.Range("C" & i).Value = "Special"
        End If
    Next
End If

Exit Sub
```

This additional block you want to add in is obviously within your first loop:

```
For i = 2 To lRow
...
    Dim Ch_lRow As Long
    Ch_lRow = child_list.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    If alert_list.Range("E" & i).Value <> "Multi" And alert_list.Range("C" & i).Value = "Corp" Then

        For k = 2 To Ch_lRow
            If alert_list.Range("F" & i).Value <> child_list.Range("B" & k).Value Then
                'do nothing
            Else
                If alert_list.Range("F" & i).Value = child_list.Range("B" & k).Value Then
                alert_list.Range("C" & i).Value = "Special"
            End If
        Next
    End If

Exit Sub

Next i
```

So this means you have an `Exit Sub` within your loop, so, within the first iteration the code will fire `Exit Sub` and your code will *do nothing* as you put it.

Remove the exit sub from this location and put it outside your `For i = 2 to lRow` loop as required.

Comment: Thank you, Worked.. Basic the place where the `Next i` was the problem??

Comment: @Fah you are welcome, you could say the placement of `Next i` was the problem, or the placement of `Exit Sub` was the problem. Either way, you were telling your code to stop running within the loop which means the code will never get passed `Exit Sub` - and in turn it would have never gotten to`Next i`.